# Why does the_permalink() method return a preview link?

Tags: wordpress, archive, permalinks

I've got the code below on an "archive.php" template file. The job is to list all archived posts on the page by year. Although the code does that, it appears that the value being returned by the_permalink() is a preview link. Therefore the post can only be accessed when the user is logged in to the back-end of the website. I'd expected that the method would return the actual (permanent) permalink instead... But maybe I'm missing something?

The "archived" status is generated via the edit-flow plugin.

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: Archive Page Template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
 
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" role="main">
 
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                 
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 
<div class="entry-content">
 
<?php the_content(); ?>


<?php
  $yearly = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status'=>'archived'));
  $prev_year = null;
  if( $yearly->have_posts() ) : while( $yearly->have_posts() ) : $yearly->the_post();
        $this_year = get_the_date('Y');
        if ($prev_year != $this_year) {
            if (!is_null($prev_year)) {
               echo '</ul>';
            }
            echo '<h3>' . $this_year . '</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
        }
        
        echo '<li>';?>
        
        <a href="<?php the_permalink($post); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        <?php
        echo '</li>';
        $prev_year = $this_year;
      endwhile;    
      echo '</ul>';

      else :?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
      <?php endif;

  wp_reset_postdata();
  
?>

 
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
 
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
 
</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
 
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Theme is called TrillingTheme and didn't include any template for archive page natively. Wordpress' version is 5.4.2

Comment: Is the post in draft mode? Also, you don't need to pass `$post` into `the_permalink()` since it's in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The post has been set from "published" to "archived". No draft mode, no.

Comment: Since the post isn't published, it will of course not let you view it unless you are logged in.

Comment: Right. That's even if the post was published before it got archived, right?

Comment: Yes, because it is no longer published.

Comment: I see. Makes sense! So the purpose is the serve archived content to the public users. I guess I could take the approach of creating a category instead of a status and have the page parsing categories instead of statuses. Will try that and I'll see where it goes. I'll post back is that succeeds for further reference. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, definitely go the category term route. That will make your life a bit easier. Good luck!

Comment: To anyone having the same issue with sharing older posts publicly on a dedicated page while removing them for index.php. Use a dedicated category and filter out from index.php + filter in on archive.php. That works.